# Adding custom data to firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a `signup screen` in my app which contains few things:

`full name`,`email` and `password`.
I want to add the users `full name` and in the future a `phone number` (for example) to the realtime database.
How can I do so?

I'm using `onCreate` from `firebase cloud functions` to add a `photoUrl` and `email` to the database, but couldn't find a way to add my own properties such `phone number`,`city`,`full name` etc.

In the end result, I want to have a registration form with all of the above properties.
How can I do so?

This is my `onCreate` method:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const ref = admin.database().ref()

exports.createUserAccount = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event=>{
  const uid = event.data.uid
  const email = event.data.email
  const photoUrl = event.data.photoUrl || 'https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/paulblartmallcop/images/9/9c/Person-placeholder-male.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120708210100'

  const newUserRef = ref.child(`/users/${uid}`)
  return newUserRef.set({
    photoUrl: photoUrl,
    email: email,
  })
});
```

How can I add more properties to the user?

Comment: how does your client side code look like?

Comment: It is a simple registration form, for example: email, password, name, phonenumber. With the method i have now, the email and photoUrl are saved to the database, how can i save the rest of the data from the form to the database?

Comment: i assume you are using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` or something similar to create user, you need to create another function to add your other details after successful

Comment: You are right, I am using createUserWithEmailAndPassword, but, this onCreate is triggered after createuseremailandpassword and adds the email to the database i need it to add the name and phone for example to the database too

Comment: yah, so you need to update that `users/userId` ref with other additional fields from client

Comment: Thanks, I will, but is there any other way to add it when the Firebase cloud function triggered?

Comment: doing this `createUserWithEmailAndPassword().then(success => // add stuff` should be enough

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to store your user details in firebase, use firebase database instead. Try this.

```
{
  "userList": {
    "JRHTHaIsjNPLXOQivY": {
      "fullName": "UmarZaii",
      "phoneNumber": "0123456789"
    },
    "JRHTHaKuTFIhnj02kE": {
      "fullName": "JohnDoe",
      "phoneNumber": "0123456789"
    }
  }
}
```

You have to create a function that saves your data to the database after you successfully created the account.

Make sure that you save all the details inside userID.

For more information on how to save data to firebase database check [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/the-beginners-guide-to-react-native-and_84.html).

Comment: Thanks, the email and photoUrl are saved inside the UID. I want to add to more data like phone number, occupation, hobbies etc. How can I take all data from my registration form to the database?

Comment: You never use firebase database before?

Comment: No, I did not. I found a tutorial on youtube, and worked with it, it worked and I do get the email and photoUrl of the user, but I don't know how can I take the data from my reg form and add it to the database under the UID

Comment: Check the link above

Comment: Is there a video tutorial? I still can't figure out how to do it on my app. I'm very new to JS and Firebase and I don't understand it :(